# In cake php need to maintain the slug if the user delete its characters

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am using cakphp1.3  My question
Its a property listing site.
For an individual property showing i have the following url http://srighar.com/property/view/66/1BHK-Test1-in-attingal-Ranchi-Jharkhand-for-sale
But the same page will appera for all the following urls
    http://srighar.com/property/view/66/1BHK-Test1-in-attingal-Ranchi-Jharkhand-for
    mysite//srighar.com/property/view/66/1BHK-Test1-in-attingal-Ranchi
    mysite//srighar.com/property/view/66/1BHK-Test1-in-attingal-Ran
    .....etc...
    mysite//srighar.com/property/view/66/

I need to maintain the first url(/property/view/66/1BHK-Test1-in-attingal-Ranchi-Jharkhand-for-sale) for all the above urls if the user accidently delete the characters on the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Check the url and redirect if necessary

All you need to do is check that the slug in the url is the current slug, and if not, [301 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142660/in-cake-php-need-to-maintain-the-slug-if-the-user-delete-its-characters) to the right url:

```
function view($id, $slug = null) {
    $record = $this->Foo->findById($id);
    if ($record['Foo']['slug'] !== $slug) {
        return $this->redirect(
            array(
                $id,
                $record['Foo']['slug']
            ),
            301
        );
    }

    ...
}
```

That way, if the slug is accidentally wrong, or if the slug changes (original record updated) the url is maintained correct and there is an enforced canonical url for each record.

Comment: You don't have to - it's an example, simply determine the current slug and compare to it.

Comment: if i use this is any problem with SEO?

Comment: what? i have a little knowledge on google spider. thats why i asked this silly question.

Comment: No, there is no negative effect doing this, there is a positive effect as it removes the possibility of duplicate content. If you permit urls `/property/1/foo`, `/property/1/bar`, `/propery/1/i-wrote-this` the same page can be seen on many different urls. If you 301 redirect to one url (consistently) there is only one url for a given record - that's a good thing.